# How can I add loop numbers and return the sum?

Tags: c#, while-loop, sum

I need to know how to have the sum of numbers that exist in a variable in a loop, I have this code:

```cs
int starting = 3
int ending = 6; 
int factor1 = 3; 
do { 
    int y = starting * factor1; 
    int sum = 0; 

    int all = sum += y; 
    Console.WriteLine("value of a: {0}", all); 
    starting = starting + 1; 
} while (starting < ending);
```

I need the code to do the multiplication of number 3 between the numbers 3 - 6, and then sum all the values. something like this:

```
(3*3)+(3*4)+(3*5)+(3*6) = 9+12+15+18 = 54
```

Comment: this is a home work, I guess. keep trying, to learn.

Comment: A `for` loop is more syntactically meaningful in this example, and you can't "sum" if you re-declare the sum each time in the loop (i.e. `sum` needs to be declared outside the loop).

Comment: You can solve your problem easily to debug your code step by step and looks what is going on exactly.

Comment: what is wrong with this question? at least it shows an attempt to solve the problem

Comment: `var result = Enumerable.Range(starting , ending - starting ).ToList().Select(i => i * factor1 ).Sum();`

Answer (score 2):

You just need to declare the variable that hold total outside the loop, so you won't overwrite it on each iteration:

```
int sum = 0;
do 
{ 
    sum += starting * factor1;
    starting++;
} while (starting <= ending);
```

You need also change the condidion `starting < ending` to `starting <= ending`, otherwise the loop will stop when it gets to the last number (6 in this case).